# How to prompt a user for a name to create a folder (bash | shell script)?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, directory-structure

First off, this is my first go at shell scripting. I have only experience in HTML and CSS :]

What I want to do is setup a simple ***folder structure*** and ***prompt the user in a dialog box to set a name*** for the root folder. I'll trigger this shell script via an OS X Service or a Keyboard Maestro hotkey.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Enter the project name:"
read -e NAME  

mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$NAME
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$NAME/subfolder1
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$NAME/subfolder2
```

Obviously there's some error - the variable won't get passed on and the root folder isn't created. I also read that I should use "dialog" to ask for the input, but I wasn't capable of writing something that works.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `echo` and `read` commands both work via a text interface, such as the Terminal window the script is running in.  If you run a script in an OS X Service, there's no Terminal-like interface, so neither command does anything useful.  (I don't know about Keyboard Maestro, but I assume it's similar.)  The simplest way to interact from a situation like this is generally to use AppleScript via the `osascript` command:

```
name="$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter the project name:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # The user pressed Cancel
    exit 1 # exit with an error status
elif [ -z "$name" ]; then
    # The user left the project name blank
    osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display alert "You must enter a project name; cancelling..." as warning'
    exit 1 # exit with an error status
fi

mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$name
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$name/subfolder1
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$name/subfolder2
```

(Note: I prefer to use lowercase variable names in the shell to avoid possible conflicts with special variables like PATH etc...)

Comment: That's great, I knew there was a smarter way to make this. Thank you for the osascript tip and the example above!

Comment: Sorry, can you please tell me what is the meaning of "fi" in this commands?

Comment: @nullmicgo: `fi` marks the end of the `if` block -- it's "if" spelled backward, similar to a `case ... esac` block.

Comment: Can this be used to produce an input dialog that doesn't have the "Cancel" button? *EDIT*: Yes, you can. I found the answer in this useful [reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/aslr_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW12).

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez: for the record, change `default answer ""'` to  `default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"'`

Answer (score 3):

Note: @Gordon Davisson's answer deserves the credit, but here are some improvements that make the code more robust (I tried to edit the original post, but it was rejected).

Improvements:

- leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed from the input
- whitespace-only input is prevented
- empty or whitespace-only input returns user to prompt after warning

Code:

```
while :; do # Loop until valid input is entered or Cancel is pressed.
    name=$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter the project name:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)
    if (( $? )); then exit 1; fi  # Abort, if user pressed Cancel.
    name=$(echo -n "$name" | sed 's/^ *//' | sed 's/ *$//')  # Trim leading and trailing whitespace.
    if [[ -z "$name" ]]; then
        # The user left the project name blank.
        osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display alert "You must enter a non-blank project name; please try again." as warning' >/dev/null
        # Continue loop to prompt again.
    else
        # Valid input: exit loop and continue.
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the script isn't being run in an interactive shell, which means you will not be able to interact with `read -e`.

I don't have an OSX box to try this out, but you could try using [CocoaDialog](http://mstratman.github.com/cocoadialog/) for a graphical dialog box.

Untested example:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=`CocoaDialog standard-inputbox --title "Project Name" --no-newline --no-cancel --informative-text "Enter the project name"`
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$NAME/subfolder1
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/$NAME/subfolder2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with CocoaDialog and the confirmation that there is no interaction possible when I leave the shell.

I'd still prefer to use the on-board tools rather than installing another application (a coding novice speaking).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`. `read` is a bash builtin, and you're not running your script with bash currently. `/bin/sh` may actually be a link to `/bin/bash`, but according to Wikipedia this depends on the specific version of OS X that you have.

Your script as it is should work correctly under bash.

Comment: It didn't work - again only the two subfolders were created. I guess I wasn't prompted because I didn't trigger it in the shell.

Comment: I didn't realize that it worked like that, I thought you were spawning the process in a terminal. Sorry about that!

Comment: No problem. I should have be more precise and appreciate that you tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

NAME is empty or it's just outputting $NAME as a string? If it's the latter you should try ~/Desktop/$(NAME)

Also, you should try [XDialog](http://xdialog.free.fr/) (or whatever is the tool in MacOS.) There are plenty of resources about using it for input handling.